# One inch margins and the geometry package

Tags: margins

Using

```
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

I can create a margin of 1 inch around my document. What would be the equivalent commands if I used the native LaTeX commands such as \textwidth, \evensidemargin, etc?

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article} 
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength\topmargin{0pt}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headheight}
\addtolength\topmargin{-\headsep}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0pt}
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\textwidth{-2in}
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight}
\addtolength\textheight{-2in}
\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document} 
\layout
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.75in}
```

If I remember correctly, these are the measurements for a 1 inch margin.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a little bit more sophisticated by setting the text height to an integer number of text lines and setting the margin pars

```
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\normalsize
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight-2in}%
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth-2in}%

\newlength\my@tdima
\newlength\my@tdimb
\newcounter{my@tcnta}
\newcounter{my@tcntb}

\setlength\my@tdima{\textheight-\topskip}%
\setcounter{my@tcnta}{\my@tdima}%
\setcounter{my@tcntb}{\baselineskip}%
\setcounter{my@tcnta}{\value{my@tcnta}/\value{my@tcntb}}%
\setlength\textheight{\baselineskip*\value{my@tcnta}+\topskip}%
\setlength\my@tdima{\paperheight-\textheight}%
\setlength\topmargin{0.5\my@tdima-\headheight-\headsep-1in}%-- Can add a ratio here
\@settopoint\topmargin

\@settopoint\textwidth
\setlength\my@tdima{\paperwidth-\textwidth}%
\setlength\oddsidemargin{0.5\my@tdima-1in}%------------------- Can add a ratio here
\@settopoint\oddsidemargin
\setlength\evensidemargin{\my@tdima-\oddsidemargin-2in}%
\@settopoint\evensidemargin

\setlength\marginparwidth{\evensidemargin+1in-\marginparsep-0.25in}%
\@settopoint\marginparwidth
\setlength\marginparsep {7pt}%
\setlength\marginparpush{7pt}%
\makeatother
```